# Can I run a program whenever I open the lid of my MacBook Air?

Tags: applescript, automator, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run AppleScript after waking from Sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45294/run-applescript-after-waking-from-sleep)

I have a program, InstantShot!, set to launch at logon and start taking a screen shot every 10 seconds.  Unfortunately, when I close the lid, it stops taking screenshots, rather than just being suspended, so I have to manually have it start doing so again each time I reopen the lid.  I'd like to create an automator app or Apple Script that would do that automatically every time I open the lid.  Can that be done?

Comment: Sleepwatcher is what you need, as per this related question/answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45296/106

Answer (score 0):

Use [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de). After downloading, read the ReadMe. It says how to install and use.